# Unable to import netmiko module

Tags: python-3.x, netmiko

I have problem when importing netmiko module. I've installed the python3-pip and trying to import netmiko module

```
root@Python,Go,Perl,PHP-1:~# python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Oct  8 2019, 13:06:37) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import netmiko
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/netmiko/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from netmiko.ssh_dispatcher import ConnectHandler
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/netmiko/ssh_dispatcher.py", line 2, in <module>
    from netmiko.a10 import A10SSH
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/netmiko/a10/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from netmiko.a10.a10_ssh import A10SSH
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/netmiko/a10/a10_ssh.py", line 3, in <module>
    from netmiko.cisco_base_connection import CiscoSSHConnection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/netmiko/cisco_base_connection.py", line 143
    msg = f"Login failed: {self.host}"
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, have a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see the `SyntaxError` that you are receiving happens at this line:

```
msg = f"Login failed: {self.host}"
```

This is because your Python version is 3.5 while the [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) were introduced in Python 3.6 with [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/). Upgrading your Python version to 3.6 or later will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Netmiko 3.x.x (and going forward requires Python 3.6 or greater). Netmiko 2.4.2 is the last version to support Python2.7 (or Python 3.5).

F-strings as mentioned above are one thing that will break if you try to use Netmiko 3.x.x with Python 3.5.